# How to change the ssh host in Vagrantfile

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, docker, vagrant

I run vagrant(1.7.2) on Mac OS(10.10.3) with [Snappy Ubuntu Core(15.04 stable), for docker](https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/boxes/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-core-stable), using VirtualBox 4.3.28 as a provider.

It all went well before I configured the "public_network" in Vagrantfile.

```
config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: 'en0:Wi-Fi (AirPort)'
```

After I turn on the "public_network" option, during "vagrant up", the guest os(Snappy Ubuntu 15.04) obtained the IP 192.168.0.13(I logged in in VirtualBox GUI), and i can manually ssh in with the IP(192.168.0.13) and vagrant private key from the Mac terminal.

My problem is the "vagrant ssh" still tried to ssh into "127.0.0.1":

```
default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
default: SSH username: ubuntu
default: SSH auth method: password
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
```

In [vagrant doc](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html) I found the **config.ssh.host** setting, but I cannot figure out a working Vagrantfile for "vagrant ssh".

Answer (score 2):

The option in your vagrant config should look something like

```
config.ssh.host = '192.168.0.13'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this

```
ssh vagrant@192.168.0.13
```